# Displaying min, max in a where clause = Too many values?

Tags: sql, oracle

First time poster/Oracle newb.

I'm trying to show min and max age in a where clause, so far I can show either min OR max, but when I try to show them both it returns

> ora-00913: too many values"

Here is my code for min/max (which works fine);

```
SELECT ROUND  
((SYSDATE - TO_DATE (DOB)) /365, 0) "AGE"  
FROM EMPLOYEE  
WHERE   
DOB = (SELECT MIN (DOB)  FROM EMPLOYEE);
```

When I put them together like -

```
SELECT ROUND  
((SYSDATE - TO_DATE (DOB)) /365, 0) "AGE"  
FROM EMPLOYEE  
WHERE   
DOB = (SELECT MIN (DOB), MAX (DOB) FROM EMPLOYEE);
```

Is where I get issues, I've tried splitting them up using AND, it doesn't help at all. Not sure what more I can do, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`Min(DOB)` is a single value so you can use `=` in your `where` clause. But `(SELECT MIN (DOB), MAX (DOB) FROM EMPLOYEE)` returns more than one value hence you have to use `IN` :

```
SELECT ROUND
((SYSDATE - TO_DATE (DOB)) /365, 0) "AGE"
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE
DOB IN (SELECT MIN (DOB), MAX (DOB) FROM EMPLOYEE);
```

Comment: This also returned too many values. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Written this way, the subquery returns TWO COLUMNS. Not only does this show little sql skill (learn more before you teach others!) - it also shows you didn't TEST your query before posting. Let the true experts post without testing; until the, test, then post.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, and you're trying to get all `EMPLOYEES` records that have a `DOB` value that is the minimum, and maximum in the database, you could `SELECT` the data, and then use `OR` to load the data.

```
DECLARE
  max_dob datetime;
  min_dob datetime;

SELECT MAX(DOB), MIN(DOB) INTO max_dob, min_dob
FROM EMPLOYEES;

SELECT ROUND
((SYSDATE - TO_DATE (DOB)) /365, 0) "AGE"
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE DOB = min_dob
OR DOB = max_dob;
```

Comment: Why does it need to be so complicated?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, following was giving "ORA-00913: too many values" error:

select f,l from r 
where n=1 
and l in ( select max(l) , min(l) from r)  ;

But following worked successfully:

select f,l from r 
where n=1 
and (l= (select max(l) from r) OR l=(select min(l) from r) ) ;

Thanks